# visual studio 2015 not clearing error list after successful build

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

Often when I am working on a project in Visual Studio 2015 I will be fixing build errors. I will see the errors and then figure out the problem, make changes to the code, save and build again.

The build will be successful as indicated in the build output window.

```
 ========== Build: 18 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 1 skipped ==========
```

But when I look at the error list, the errors are still there.

[image]
Why is this error showing up if the build worked?

Edit:
@MethodMan request the source of the error. It is an actual valid error from within the test project.

```
    public void GetCustomerStatusInfoReportTest()
    {
        ReportManager target = new ReportManager();
        List<GetCustomerStatusInfoResult> actual;

        int resultCount;
        actual = target.GetCustomerStatusInfoReport(1, DateTime.UtcNow.AddMonths(-3), DateTime.UtcNow, null, null, null, null, null);
        resultCount = actual.Count;
        Assert.IsTrue(resultCount > 0);
    }
```

Comment: Try cleaning the solution and then rebuilding, do they still show after that?

Comment: I have tried cleaning the solution and the error is still there.

Comment: Unload and reload the project from the solution.

Comment: double click on the error and post what the code looks like when it takes you to that error..show us where you are making the call to the `GetCustomerStatusInfoReport`

Comment: Remove manually "bin" and "obj" directories and try it again. If the error persists... I suggest reporting the error to Microsoft.

Comment: Does the class that contains the method 'GetCustomerStatusInfoReport' have the same name as its class? And does it inherit from some some other class?

Comment: Did you build all when getting the successful message or just the source code? I see that the error message appears in some "Test" class, which probably is in a different project. On the other hand, the class says something about "Report"; is it some SQL Server Reporting Services report? maybe it needs some kind of "regeneration".

Comment: @MethodMan You know, that test project is not getting built unless you specifically build it yet it is still showing a build error.

Comment: @Luis We are not using SSRS.

Comment: It is a code analysis error, not a compile error.  You are supposed to fix the code or suppress the message.

Comment: what project do you have set as the start up project.. obviously there must be an error

Comment: @HansPassant This makes sense. In prior versions on Visual Studio, the only errors shown in this window are a result of a build. I guess a new feature in 2015 is looking at other projects I am not building,

Comment: also your method expects `11` parameters but in your code you're only passing `8` parameters.. therefore the error that you are getting is correct

Comment: Don't we all feel pretty stupid for not seeing that earlier - nice work @MethodMan

Comment: @MethodMan Yes, as soon as I add the missing parameters the error goes away.

Comment: no problem.. next time learn to read as well as understand what the compiler error are telling you.. you wasted a lot of time for something so simple..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll post an answer in case anyone else get confused by this.

After many helpful comments, it turns out the error is in a test project that is not a dependency and not getting built. @HansPassant pointed out this is not a build error but a "code analysis error".

I looked it up and a new feature in 2015 is to show Build + IntelliSense errors in this window. I could suppress the error by selecting "Build Only" but I like the new feature  now that I understand what is going on and fixed the code.

[image]